# Error warnings.filters.pop(0) IndexError: pop from empty list in clf.fit

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, supervised-learning

I get the following error while learning new model in python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Project/ThesisFinal/FrameWork/eval.py", line 46, in evaluate
    clf.fit ( train,trainLabel.iloc[:,0] )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 316, in fit
    random_state=random_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/base.py", line 130, in _make_estimator
    _set_random_states(estimator, random_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/base.py", line 52, in _set_random_states
    for key in sorted(estimator.get_params(deep=True)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 241, in get_params
    warnings.filters.pop(0)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Here is the part of the code which produces the error:

```
train= pd.read_csv (
            "%s/%s/LabelDataSet.csv" % (dirpath,dirname),encoding='utf-8')
test= pd.read_csv (
            "%s/%s/TestDataSet.csv" % (dirpath,dirname),encoding='utf-8')
traincl=list(train.columns.values)
testcl=list(test.columns.values)
los=list(set(traincl)-set(testcl))
d = dict.fromkeys ( los,0 )
test.assign ( **d )
test.columns = test.columns.astype ( int )
test.sort_index ( axis=1,inplace=True )
clf = RandomForestClassifier ( n_estimators=100 )
clf.fit ( train,trainLabel.iloc[:,0] )
```

Whats the problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using? Please add some contents of both files. Also whats `trainLabel`? Please make [a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seems like you have encountered a known bug of scikit-learn when running in python3. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7346

Comment: @VivekKumar, so it hasn't solved?

Comment: Depends on your setup and whole code (if using multi-threading). This issue may not come up on multiple runs of the code.

Comment: Its version is 0.19.1. and it is multi-threading.

Comment: So If I run each thread separately but at the same time it would be solved?